# Парсинг таблицы #Powershell

Tags: html, powershell, таблицы

Необходимо вытянуть таблицу из html - разметки. Для примера взяли начальную страницу (весь сайт сверстан в табличной форме). Пытаюсь получить с помощью PowerShell и Selenium\WebDriver.dll. Как получить необходимый тэг, проблем не составило, но вот как все остальное реализовать???? Получить необходимо результат в табличной форме. 
Код страницы из которой получить таблицу`

```html
<div class="loginContainer">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td class="loginLogo"><img alt="HP" src="/sm/cwc/images/backgrounds/logo_hp_largemasthead.gif"></td>
        <td class="loginTitle">Таблица 1</td>
        <td class="loginImage"><div class="imgSpacer">&nbsp;</div></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="loginForm">
    <form id="Login" name="Login" autocomplete="on" onSubmit="setCwcToken()" style="margin-top:4px;" method="POST" action="/sm/index.do">
      <table id="cwc_custom_loginform" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td class="loginLabel">&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="loginInput">
            
              <div id="WarningMsgWrapperDiv" style='visibility:hidden; background:transparent url(/sm/cwc/images/msg_warning.gif) no-repeat; margin-top:10px; padding-left:20px; line-height:16px;'>
                &nbsp;
              </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="loginLabel">
            <label for="LoginUsername" id="LoginUsernameLabel" class="loginLabel">Имя пользователя:</label>
          </td>
          <td class="loginInput">
            <input id="LoginUsername" type="text" name="user.id" tabindex="1">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="loginLabel">
            <label for="LoginPassword" id="LoginPasswordLabel" class="loginLabel">Пароль:</label>
          </td>
          <td class="loginInput">
            <input id="LoginPassword" type="password" tabindex="2">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="loginLabel">
            <label for="LoginLanguage" id="Locale" class="loginLabel">Язык:</label>
          </td>
          <td class="loginInput">
            <select name="L.language" id="LoginLanguage" tabindex="3">
            
            <option value="ru" selected = "true">Русский</option>
            
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="loginLabel">&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="loginInput">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="x-btn-wrap x-btn" id="clrBtn"
                onmouseup="removeClass(this, ' x-btn-click');"
                onmousedown="addClass(this, ' x-btn-click');"
                onmouseout="removeClass(this, ' x-btn-over');"
                onmouseover="removeClass(this, ' x-btn-click');addClass(this, ' x-btn-over');">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="x-btn-left cwc-btn-left"><i>&nbsp;</i></td>
                  <td class="x-btn-center cwc-btn-center">
                    <em unselectable="on">
                      <input type="submit"
                        id="loginBtn" class="x-btn-text cwc-btn-text"
                        onblur="removeClass('clrBtn', ' x-btn-over');"
                        onfocus="addClass('clrBtn', ' x-btn-over');"
                        value="&nbsp;Вход в систему&nbsp;">
                    </em>
                  </td>
                  <td class="x-btn-right cwc-btn-right"><i>&nbsp;</i></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="loginLabel">&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="loginInput">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div id="licensingLogos" class="loginLogos">
              
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="loginCopyright">
            <div id="cwc_copyright">
              &copy; 1994-2014 Компания.<br/> Данное программное <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
            </div>
           </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <input type="hidden" name="type" id="type" value="login">
      <input type="hidden" id="xHtoken" name="xHtoken"/>
      <input type="hidden" id="old.password"  name="old.password"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="event" id="event" value="0"/>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Начало скрипта PowerShell

```
 Add-Type -Path "c:\Selenium\WebDriver.dll"
$env:PATH += ";c:\Selenium"
$browser = New-Object "OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver"
$browser.Navigate().GoToURL("http://....")
$tables = $browser.FindElements($selBy::TagName('table'))
$rows = $tables.FindElements($selBy::TagName('td'))
$resultObject = [Ordered] @{ }
for ($counter = 0; $counter -lt $rows.Count; $counter++)
        { .... Цикл не могу реализовать корректно   }   
[PSCustomObject]$resultObject
```

Comment: Лучше конечно на C# реализовать, но C# не дружу вообще ни как

Answer (score 0):

Берешь [HTMLAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/)

Для примера использую таблицу [отсюда](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp).

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\...\lib\netstandard2.0\HtmlAgilityPack.dll")

$doc = [HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument]::new()
$doc.Load('s:\SCRIPTS\htmlAP.html')
$table = $doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes('//table')[0] # Первая таблица в докементе

$headers = @( $table.SelectNodes('/table/tr/th') | ForEach-Object { return $_.InnerText.Trim() } )

$rows = $table.SelectNodes('./tr[./td]')

$retObjects = [System.Collections.Generic.List[PSCustomObject]]::new()

for($i = 0; $i -lt $rows.Count; $i++)
{
    $values = $null
    $row = $rows[$i]
    $values = @( $row.SelectNodes('./td') | ForEach-Object { return $_.InnerText.Trim() } )
    if ($values.Count -ne $headers.Count)
    {
        Write-Warning "Тут неправильные пчёлы"
        continue
    }

    $retObjectHT = @{}
    for ($j = 0; $j -lt $headers.Count; $j++)
    {
        $retObjectHT[$headers[$j]] = $values[$j]
    }
    $retObjects.Add([PSCustomObject]$retObjectHT)
}

$retObjects | Out-GridView
```